# Kubernetes (GKE) on Google Cloud : Get Real IP of the client from Traefik

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, traefik, traefik-ingress, clientip

I am using Google Kubernetes Engine on Google Cloud Platform (GCP): I am using traefik ingress in GKE.

How do I get the real source IP of the client in the backend services behind traefik ?

I tried setting externalTrafficPolicy: Local in GKE but, the Kubernetes Docs say that it will cause a problem in uniform load balancing.

Can you please help me get the real source IP of the client ?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip

Comment: I tried this option. But it is mentioned in the doc that setting externalTrafficPolicy: Local will  result in uneven load balancing. Is there a way to solve this issue ?

Comment: What Kubernetes version on GKE and traefik version are you using? Did you check this thread: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/2311 about `X-Forwarded-For`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, PjotesS

Kubernetes Version : Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13+", GitVersion:"v1.13.12-gke.25",  GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-14T06:01:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.11b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}


How do I find traefik ingress version ?

The link you provided did not help me.

Comment: Did you use any tutorials? How did you deploy traefik Helm, own config? You mentioned that you have tried to use externalTrafficPolicy: Local, were you able to get SourceIP or you have issue with LoadBalancing? Could you share your config YAMLs (Traefik, Deployment, Service, etc.)?

Comment: To check traefik version you can use: 
`kubectl exec -it <traefik-controller_pod> -n <traefik_namesapce>  -- traefik version` or `kubectl get pod <pod-name> -n <namespace>  -o custom-columns=CONTAINER:.spec.containers[0].name,IMAGE:.spec.containers[0].image`

Comment: @Prakash Premkumar could you provide information from previous comments?